# See all commit messages of a file CVS

Tags: cvs

By the

```
                            cvs admin -mrev:msg
```

command I've changed commit message of wrong revision.
Now I want to find the old correct message of that revision.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have a different local working copy of the file, you could use

```
cvs diff <filename>
```

I also found this which may be helpful if you don't have a working copy available:
http://java.dzone.com/tips/how-display-cvs-log-messages

Comment: cvs diff shows differences between your local file and the file in repository, so it can't help me in this case.
As for log messages, I've tried to use cvs log command, but it didn't show changed messages.